# PyQt 5.10 - Enabling High DPI support for MacOS, poor Pixmap quality

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

My PyQt application running on MacOS (with a High DPI Retina Display) does not seem to work correctly. For example, the picture below shows a Pixmap size 30x30 (left) next to a manually scaled image (right) via the Preview app (MacOSX default image viewer). Both are visually the same dimensions on my screen, but notice how they have different resolutions - the pixmap on the left has significantly lower quality.

[image: High DPI problem example]

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211006/optimising-python-qt-apps-on-retina-displays) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) that running PyQt 5.10 should be enough to automatically support high DPI displays on MacOS, but from personal research it seems like [the application is being rendered at the “normal” resolution and scaled up.](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/04/25/retina-display-support-for-mac-os-ios-and-x11/)

Is there any ideas on how to fix this? I tried setting `QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)` and `QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_DisableHighDpiScaling)` but neither attribute being set seems to be doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with the low-density, poor resolution pixmaps by inferring the fact that a 30x30 pixmap ought not to be as large as it was on my screen - in the end, I found that I needed to use `setDevicePixelRatio(X)` where `X` is a float greater than 1.0. See the below example:

```
# Device pixel ratio must be set AFTER loading the data!
print(pix_map.devicePixelRatio()) # 1.0
pix_map.loadFromData(image_data)
pix_map.setDevicePixelRatio(2.0)
print(pix_map.devicePixelRatio()) # 2.0
```

Comment: Would anyone know how to find the highest `devicePixelRatio` value for your computer's display? 2.0 might not always be the best setting to default this pixmap to.